# Импорт файла PHP в bundle

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, phpmailer

У меня сайт с формой обратной связи, где за отправку email отвечает php-файл. Хочу с помощью `webpack` скомпилировать `bundle`, соответственно думаю, как туда переместить файл `php`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в зависимости **CopyWebpackPlugin**:

```
npm i copy-webpack-plugin
```

или

```
yarn add copy-webpack-plugin
```

Дальше подключите его в `webpack.config.js` таким образом:

```
const `CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')`

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: __dirname + '/src/assets/php/email.php', // откуда
                    to: __dirname + '/build' // куда
                }
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```